# What is the best way to make a socat link to a udp rs232 connected serial device persistent?

Tags: linux, tcp, serial-port, udp, socat

I have a connection that seems to work to an RS232 serial device to Ethernet server (hardware device). I want to make it persistent. What is the best way to do that? I'm using this command now:

```
sudo socat pty,link=/dev/ttySx udp:192.168.1.50:23
```

I would like to make that stay open all the time, including after reboots, so I can talk to the device `/dev/ttySx` but I'm not sure the best way to do that.

Edit: I am running this on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting up a systemd service. Create a file such as `/etc/systemd/system/myttySx.service` holding for example:

```
[Unit]
Description=socat ttySx to udp
After=network-online.target
[Service]
Restart=restart-always
RestartSec=10
ExecStart=/usr/bin/socat pty,link=/dev/ttySx udp:192.168.1.50:23
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and enable it and start it (once only) as root with:

```sh
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable myttySx
systemctl start myttySx
```

systemd on Ubuntu 18.04 is a bit old, so this may not be correct for that version. Check with `systemctl status myttySx`. Post each problem in a new question so others may answer.